# Generating statistical distributions and sorting them

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, numpy

I am creating two distributions as shown below.

```
# Binomial distribution
a = np.random.binomial(3, 0.5, 5000)
a.sort()

# Normal distribution
b = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev, size_dist)
b.sort()
```

I want to know does ***sorting*** the array ruins the distributions i.e. do the order of random numbers in array make up the distribution or they can be sorted and doesn't matter?

Comment: The usual descriptive statistics (mean, median, var, SD) are not affected by sorting. Also some inferences are still possible (testing normality, finding CI for population mean, etc.). However, some tests for randomness are impossible after sorting. (For example, runs are destroyed by sorting, so a runs test is impossible.)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to check that the distribution doesn't change is by plotting the distributions under the sorted and not sorted versions and observe if somethings changes.

In general, the elements of your arrays are realizations of the distributions, so it doesn't matter in which order these realizations appear.

For example, let $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}$ be a sample from a $N(0,4)$, with values $5,-2,1$, even if I sort them $X_{2}=-2,X_{3}=1,X_{1}=5$ this is still going to be a sample from the distribution $N(0,4)$

Answer (score 1):

@Fiodor1234 (+1) has discussed some of the things that are unchanged by sorting.

However, one way to check whether whether software is
really giving a sequence of independent observations
is to look at runs for discrete distributions and runs above and below the mean for continuous data. Sorting destroys information about runs.

Here such a sample:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(100)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-3.0388 -0.5620  0.1200  0.1089  0.7394  3.2016
d = sign(x-mean(x));  d
d
  [1]  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1
 [26]  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1
 [51] -1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1
 [76] -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1
```

In R, the procedure `rle` (for Run Length Encoding) finds how many runs of `1`s and `-1`s there are. And from that
we can know the number $(46)$ of runs (of both kinds).

```
rle(d)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:46] 2 3 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 ...
  values : num [1:46] 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 ...
length(rle(d)$val)
[1] 46
```

Theoretical results about distributions of runs are [available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test). However, we use a simulation below to get the distribution of such runs in a normal sample of $n=100.$
The number of runs averages about 51 with a SD of about 5. And 95% of run counts are between 41 and 61. (The distribution of the number of runs is approximately normal.)

If a "randomly" generated normal distributed standard
normal random samples do not have a number of runs
above and below the mean between 41 and 61, it is fair
to whether the generation process is random. In particular, the sample from seed `2020` above, with 46 such runs, seems OK.

```
set.seed(1129)
m = 10^5; nr.runs = numeric(m); n = 100
for(i in 1:m) {
 x = rnorm(n);  d = sign(x-mean(x))
 nr.runs[i] = length(rle(d)$val) }
mean(nr.runs);  sd(nr.runs)
[1] 50.82255
[1] 4.967916
quantile(nr.runs, c(.025, .975))
  2.5% 97.5% 
    41    61
```

Of course if you **sort** a random sample, then it
will have two runs.

```
y = sort(rnorm(100));  d = sign(y-mean(y))
length(rle(d)$val)
[1] 2
```

*Notes:* (1) Runs tests are not the only way to explore or test for lack of independence. See [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498243/what-is-a-good-auto-correlation-value/498248#498248) for a brief introduction to autocorrelateion and associated tests and graphics. There is no point in finding autocorrelatiions for sorted data.

(2) I trust the procedure `rnorm` in R because it has been extensively vetted, so it
seems OK to use it to get the distribution of runs by simulation in R. See the link above
to the Wald-Wolfowitz run test for theoretical details.

Comment: Thanks. However, for a distribution to be normal, poisson,or binomial etc. does the 'randomness' in data really matter? Because even if I sort them, their plots remain the same. So, regardless of order and as well as randomness, I can still say my data follows those distributions, right?

Comment: Yes, randomness matters for any distribution. If I sampled 10 observations from POIS(7), it would be very suspicious to get the observations in the order 3,  4,  5,  5,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9, 12. You might want to look at a runs test or an autocorrelation plot for Binomial, Poisson, or any other kind of simulated sample.